# Create an HTML unordered list in SQL

Tags: html, sql

I am trying to create an unordered list of html links in SQL, and output the results as the desired unordered list.

```
select tblRoster.ID,tblRoster.pRank,tblRoster.pName,tblRoster.pSquad,
(select '<ul>' + stuff((select '<li>'+ '<'+ 'img src=' + pm.dLink from tblPlayerMedals pm where tblRoster.ID = pm.pID order by dID asc for xml path('')),1,0,'') + ' /></li>' + '</ul>')  AS dLink,
stuff((select ','+ pm.dName from tblPlayerMedals pm where tblRoster.ID = pm.pID order by dID asc for xml path('')),1,1,'') [dName]
from tblRoster
order by 1
```

The output shows the results as plain text and the closing tags for each element - the image,list,and unordered list elements - are not rendered.

Here is a sample of what renders in the aspx page:

```
<li><img src=https://myimage.jpg?w=84&h=32&pad=0<li><img src=https://myimage.jpg?w=84&h=32&pad=0
```

Comment: This sort of thing is much easier to do in your application layer.

Comment: While I'm sure this is possible, it's honestly a terrible idea for a few reasons; firstly SQL Server was not designed specifically to create html so creating, debugging and maintaining html within SQL is much more difficult than in other languages/frameworks designed to create html, secondly it wasn't designed to deliver html, it's network protocol does not support web browsers or debugging network calls so it's much harder to debug.

Comment: I actually did try to write a HTML generic control, however when I called the RenderControl function, nothing rendered. Any ideas?

Comment: My mistake. I actually used a HTMLTextwriter object to create a control, but it never renders.